# Excel Scatter Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am try to create a chart that shows the difference in pay between male and female. I want pay at the top/bottom, sector on the left, and a male/female icon and the pay points. I can not seem to achieve this. The closest I have come is a scatter chart that plots the pay points but then can not add the sector. I will need to add more sectors as well.[image: scatter chart] Is there a way to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g9DK5noi1s) is something you are after?

Comment: @JvdV Thanks but no

Comment: This made me think of another video by the same person as JvdV's link.  She has a bunch of videos about creating info charts in Excel using symbols.  Your example is much more straightforward than the elaborate stuff she does.  I've never tried this, and don't have ready access to Excel, but I think it's just a question of using symbols for the markers instead of dots, and I think it's a built-in feature of recent versions of Excel.

Comment: @fixer1234 I thought it would be something easy do to with markers as well, but trying it I kept on getting stuck. I must be missing something.

Comment: It looks like you've already got the markers.  The issue is including the sectors on the Y axis?  I think your problem is with how the data is structured.  I don't have access to Excel, but I roughed something out in WPS Office, which sucks for charting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvEua.png.  The data is structured with sectors in rows and gender in columns.  I picked an XY chart from the limited choices.  I had to add numerical values as placeholders for the Y axis.  (cont'd)

Comment: Series are in columns,  I had to manually reassign ranges in the series definitions to make the values the X axis and the category numbers the Y axis.  I would substitute the sector names on the chart.  Excel might have a chart type that allows a numeric variable for X and categories for Y.  But this got me the basic structure you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you don't think what I linked you to isn't what you are after. A scatter plot won't work with text labels as it expects numeric values. The information shown in the linked video is quite clear and I was able to re-create what you are after fairly simple:

[image]

With this data:

[image]

I added a column `Scatter_y` for later use since scatterplots won't take textual values but numeric ones.

What were the steps I took:

- Select `A2:C5` and insert a vertical grouped bar chart. Select one series (click on a bar) and overlap the two series a 100%.

[image]

- Right click the chart and add two new series. Name them e.g.: `Icon-Male` and `Icon-Female` and pick the appropriate data form column B or C.
- When added, right click the newly added bar chart, and choose to change graph type.
- On the right screen you can now for both new added series choose a scatter plot:

[image]

- Select `Icon-Male` series, right click and edit series: X-values are `B2:B5` and Y-values are `D2:D5`. Do the same thing for `Icon-Female` series according to the appropriate ranges.
- Now you'll notice the scatter plot used the Y-axis on the right side. Now click that axis and under axis options, fixe the minimum to `0,5` and maximum to `4,5`:

[image]

- Next up is adding in the two icons on the appropriate series. I suppose you know how to add the two icons to your sheet, color and resize them. After you done doing that just copy the male icon and select the `Icon-Male` series and paste (Ctrl+V for that matter). Do the same thing with the female icon.

[image]

- Now it's a matter of use no-fill on the bar chart, removing the y-axis on the right and format to your liking. Result is the picture on the top.

Comment: The end result of the video didn't look like what I wanted as my end result, so maybe I overlooked it, but your answer is really helpful. Thanks.